# how display json data using highcharts

Tags: jquery, json, highcharts

I have some json data from my backend rails api which I am trying to integrate into highcharts. I'm able to grab the json data using $.getJSON but i'm having trouble rendering the chart. I get this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined "

As per the documentation im using this to set the series and my chart is a simple bar chart. And my json data is below.

```
$.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
    options.series[0].data = data;
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});


[{ id: 1, 
  state: "Massachusetts",
  city: "Boston"
},
{
  id: 2,
  state: "Massachusetts",
  city: "Boston"
},
{
 id: 3,
 state: "Massachusetts",
 city: "Boston"
},
{
 id: 4,
 state: "Massachusetts",
 city: "Boston"
},
{
 id: 5,
 state: "Massachusetts",
 city: "Boston"
},
{
 id: 6,
 state: "Massachusetts",
 city: "Boston"
},
{
 id: 7,
 state: "Massachusetts",
 city: "Boston"
}]
```

Comment: show full code please

Comment: Use [jslint](http://www.jslint.com/) to check if your json is valid. Morever fields are incorrect, your json should looks like somehting like in the example: http://jsfiddle.net/sbochan/twkn1bdm/. See the json structure.